# Apostroph in "ins" verboten?

Tags: preposition

Ich weiß, dass der Auslassungs-Apostroph in Wörtern wie "ins" nicht vonnöten ist. (§97 der Rechtschreibregeln, wenn ich mich nicht täusche.) Allerdings haben wir derzeit die Diskussion, ob es nur optional, oder sogar verboten ist. Was ist nun richtig? In den Rechtschreibregeln habe ich nur gelesen, dass es ausgelassen werden *kann*, nicht ausgelassen werden *muss*.

Comment: Bei "ins" würde ich einen Apostroph merkwürdig finden, unabhängig davon, ob man den setzen dürfte. "Ins" ist für mich ein eigenständiges Wort, dass es die Kurzform für "in das" ist, ist irrelevant.

Comment: "Bei den allgemein üblichen Verschmelzungen von Präposition (Verhältniswort) und Artikel setzt man in der Regel keinen Apostroph." ... ist das schon ein Verbot? http://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/rechtschreibregeln/apostroph

Comment: @Em1: Lustigerweise ist das das einzige Wort, bei dem bei mir das Problem auftrat, da ich es genau so gelernt habe.

Comment: Vielleicht weil es besser wäre, wenn eines dort stünde.

Comment: @Code1001 Vielleicht aber auch nicht?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Unnötigerweise hält sich der Duden hier mit der Floskel *in der Regel* ein Hintertürchen offen. In *Richtiges und gutes Deutsch* (Artikel *Apostroph*, 1.2) macht er eigentlich eine glasklare Ansage für Verschmelzungen aus Präposition und Artikel:

1. Sind sie allgemein üblich (*ins, übers, ums*), enthalten sie keinen Apostroph.
2. Sind sie mundartlich oder umgangssprachlich und führen zu unüblichen Konsonantenverbindungen (*auf'm, in'n*), werden sie »häufiger mit Apostroph« geschrieben.

Warum der Duden im ersten Fall *in der Regel* ergänzt, ist mir schleierhaft. Man müsste eine allgemein übliche Verschmelzung finden, die aus irgendeinem Grund doch einen Apostroph benötigt, um zu dieser Regel eine Ausnahme zu konstruieren.

Comment: Alles, was im Duden steht, hat *im Prinzip* die Einlassung *üblicherweise* und *in der Regel* - Rechtschreibregeln sind eine dokumentarische Momentaufnahme, kein in Stein gemeißeltes Gesetz. Recht hast du trotzdem.